# How to add PATH variable to sudo in Fabric

Tags: path, fabric

when I try to use fabric to deploy Apache server remotely using Fabric, I encountered a problem. I tried to add a new path to the PATH variable first using sudo(), then I tried to echo $PATH using sudo() too. However, I found that it looks like the new path wasn't added to PATH at all. As a result, I cannot execute the bins in that path via sudo().

```
[name@IP:port] Executing task 'reboot'
[name@IP:port] sudo: export PATH=$PATH:/new/path/to/add/install/bin
[name@IP:port] out: sudo password: 

[name@IP:port] sudo: echo $PATH
[name@IP:port] out: sudo password:
[name@IP:port] out: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Could anyone tell me how to add a path variable to sudo command in Fabric? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. It should be habit to always give a full path to the executable when running as root, to avoid having trojan horses being pushed into your PATH.
2. Setting an environment variable via `export` works only for the *current* shell session - which is the one invoked by `sudo`. Once your command (`export`, in this case) is executed, the shell exits, and takes your environment variable with it. The next time you execute `sudo`, a new shell (with default environment) is set up, which does know nothing about your previous `export`.
3. The configuration file `/etc/sudoers` usually contains an entry like `Defaults env_reset`, the effect of which is that environment variables set in the *calling* environment are *not* copied to the environment invoked by `sudo`, so calling `export` in your current environment and *then* executing `sudo` does not work either. This is done for security reasons (ref. 1) above).
4. It is possible to set up `/etc/sudoers` to make exceptions to 3), via `env_keep`. Refer to `man sudoers` for details. However, see 1) - it is *not* a good idea.
5. There is the `-E` option to `sudo`, which allows to keep the caller's environment (including e.g. an extended `PATH`), but this requires `SETENV` being set in `/etc/sudoers`. Again, refer to `man sudoers` for details, and be mindful of 1).

Comment: The funny thing is that I add like <pre>Defaults !env_reset<code> to the sudoer file. When I log in the remote server and try to execute command with sudo, it works. The problem is when I do the same thing using Fabric remotely,it doesn't work. It looks like Fabric resets the path, which is wierd.

Comment: @byteocean: OK... can't help you there, since I have no experience with Fabric.

Answer (score -1):

use

```py
sudo('PATH=$PATH:/new/path/to/add/install/bin commad')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: It might also not work with `shell=False` in environments where running shells via sudo is restricted.